# pickle module seems to watch the original object

Tags: python, pickle

Writing this code:

```
>>> class T:
>>>     version = '1.0'
>>> import pickle
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(T)
>>> T.version = '2.0'
>>> PT = pickle.loads(pickled)
>>> PT.version
>>> '2.0'
```

Why does that happen? Should not be PT.version == '1.0' as it was when pickled?
On the other hand, I'm seeing that

```
 >>> T
 <class '__main__.T'>
 >>> PT
 <class '__main__.T'>
 >>> id(PT) == id(T)
 True
```

Are python class objects (not class instances, the class object itself) singletons or something like that? I would expect that there would be two different classes now but there seems to be just one, and two different aliases or references or names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions and classes are both essentially pickled as references to a global variable, note, this is why you cannot pickle lambdas, or classes and functions not defined at the top level. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully
> qualified” name reference, not by value. 2 This means that only the
> function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the
> function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its
> function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be
> importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain
> the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised. 3
>
> Similarly, classes are pickled by named reference, so the same
> restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that none of
> the class’s code or data is pickled

Note, the docs also provide an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#reducer-override) of how to override this behavior for a class object:

```
import io
import pickle

class MyClass:
    my_attribute = 1

class MyPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def reducer_override(self, obj):
        """Custom reducer for MyClass."""
        if getattr(obj, "__name__", None) == "MyClass":
            return type, (obj.__name__, obj.__bases__,
                          {'my_attribute': obj.my_attribute})
        else:
            # For any other object, fallback to usual reduction
            return NotImplemented

f = io.BytesIO()
p = MyPickler(f)
p.dump(MyClass)

del MyClass

unpickled_class = pickle.loads(f.getvalue())

assert isinstance(unpickled_class, type)
assert unpickled_class.__name__ == "MyClass"
assert unpickled_class.my_attribute == 1
```